# Get difference with closest previous row in a group which meets criterion

Tags: r

I'm trying, for each row, to calculate the difference with the closest previous row belonging to the same group which meets a certain criterion.

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
s <- read.table(text = "Visit_num Patient Day Admitted
1 1 2015/01/01 Yes
2 1 2015/01/10 No         
3 1 2015/01/15 Yes
4 1 2015/02/10 No                                       
5 1 2015/03/08 Yes
6 2 2015/01/01 Yes                                       
7 2 2015/04/01 No
8 2 2015/04/10 No
9 3 2015/04/01 No
10 3 2015/04/10 No", header = T, sep = "")
```

For each Visit_num and for each Patient, I'd like to get the difference with the closest row for which the patient was admitted (i.e. Yes). Note column day is ordered by day, and time unit for this example is days.
Here is what I wanted my dataframe to look like:

```
Visit_num Patient   Day      Admitted  Diff_days
   1        1    2015/01/01    Yes     NA
   2        1    2015/01/10     No     9
   3        1    2015/01/15    Yes     14
   4        1    2015/02/10     No     26
   5        1    2015/03/08    Yes     52
   6        2    2015/01/01    Yes     NA
   7        2    2015/04/01     No     90
   8        2    2015/04/10     No     99
   9        3    2015/04/01     No     NA
   10       3    2015/04/10     No     NA
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`.  Convert the 'Day' to `Date` class, `arrange` by 'Patient', 'Day', grouped by 'Patient' get the difference of adjacent 'Day', create a group 'grp' based on the occurrence of 'Yes' in 'Admitted' and take the cumulative sum of 'Diff_days'

```
library(tidyverse)
s %>%
    mutate(Day = ymd(Day)) %>%
    arrange(Patient, Day) %>% 
    group_by(Patient) %>% 
    mutate(Diff_days = c(NA, diff(Day))) %>% 
    group_by(grp = cumsum(lag(Admitted == "Yes", default = TRUE)), add = TRUE) %>%         
    mutate(Diff_days = cumsum(replace_na(Diff_days, 0))) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-grp) %>%
    mutate(Diff_days = na_if(Diff_days, 0))
# A tibble: 8 x 5
#  Visit_num Patient Day        Admitted Diff_days
#      <int>   <int> <date>     <fct>        <dbl>
#1         1       1 2015-01-01 Yes             NA
#2         2       1 2015-01-10 No               9
#3         3       1 2015-01-15 Yes             14
#4         4       1 2015-02-10 No              26
#5         5       1 2015-03-08 Yes             52
#6         6       2 2015-01-01 Yes             NA
#7         7       2 2015-04-01 No              90
#8         8       2 2015-04-10 No              99
```

Comment: Sorry, quick follow up. What if instead of Day as date (2015-01-01) I had a datetime object (2015-01-01 00:15)? Would "ymd" and "diff" functions work?

Comment: @DEYVISONMEDEIROS  If it is already in Datetime, class then you can just do `mutate(Day = as.Date(Day)) %>%`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @akrun. That worked!

Comment: I found only one problem with the solution: in case the patient was never admitted, I'm still getting a cumulative sum for diff_days. Any way to avoid that (I wanted it to be 0 or NA)? I have modified the example to make it more clear

Comment: @DEYVISONMEDEIROS  You make add an `if/else` condition to this, i.e. `group_by(Patient) %>% mutate(Diff_days = if(all(Admitted == "No")) NA else c(NA, diff(Day)))` and make changes in the rest of the code